# Method in interface implementing class not visible in service class

Tags: java, interface

I have a method defined in an implementing `@Repository` class that is an extension of an abstract base class and implements an interface.  However, a method defined in the `@Repository` class is not visible in the `@Service` class, and I am not sure why.

I have a `@Service` class defined as

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private IJpaRepository categoryRepository;

    public CategoryService(){ } 

    /* service methods */

    public List<Category> findTopLevelCategories(){
         //findTopLevelCategories is not visible here
         return categoryRepository.findTopLevelCategories();
    }

}
```

where `IJpaRepository` is an interface defined by

```
public interface IJpaRepository<T> {

    T findOne(int id);
    List<T> findAll();
    T create(T entity);
    T update(T entity);
    void delete(T entity);
    void deleteById(int id);

}
```

and the @Repository is defined as an extension of an abstract class implementing the interface above:

```
@Repository
public class CategoryRepository extends AbstractJpaRepository<Category> implements IJpaRepository<Category> {

    public List<Category> findTopLevelCategories(){
        Query queryCategoryTopLevel = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("findTopLevelCategories");
        return queryCategoryTopLevel.getResultList();
    } 

    /* Other overriding methods */

}
```

My best guess is that it is due to the `@Autowired` binding to the `IJpaRepository`, rather than the actual implementing `CategoryRepository` class.  Without making any changes to `IJpaRepository` interface, how can I make the new method defined in `CategoryRepository` visible to the `@Service` class?

Comment: Your best guess is correct. You need to define an `iterface` that `extends IJpaRepository<Category>` and `implements` that. Then autowire the `interface`.

Comment: It's not even Spring related, in fact. You have a reference to an instance of IJpaRepository. So the only methods available are the ones defined in IJpaRepository (and in Object). The only way to call the method findTopLevelCategories() would be to cast the categoryRepository reference to CategoryRepository. But that, in turn, has a good chance to fail because Spring might inject a proxy, and not an actual instance of CategoryRepository.